# storing r, g and b components in a 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Say, I am scanning a list of triangles and each triangle has a fixed r,g,b value (color). I want to store the r,g,b components of each triangle in a 2D array and retrieve them later on. If the width and height of the screen is w and h respectively, I can declare an array of size w*h but how can I store 3 components (r,g,b) at a place in c++?

Comment: You can use structures. example: `struct color{int r,g,b;}; color* array = new color[w*h];`

Comment: It can be an array of struct{r, g, b} but usually you will just pack three bytes into one integer and store the pixel's rgb value as one integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
constexpr std::size_t w = /* some constant */;
constexpr std::size_t h = /* some constant */;

struct Color {
    int r, g, b;
};
Color color[w][h];
```

store in structures

Comment: Note that this code will work when `w` and `h` is constant, but variable-length array is not supported in standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways you can do it... you can use bitmasks and bit flags to store and retrieve the values of a 2d int array, you can make a custom struct or class called color like this:

```
struct Color
{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};
```

Then declare your array as:

```
Color screenColors[1024][768];
```

You can always declare the 1024 and 768 values as constant integers and use them instead of hard-coding the value.

If you would like more information about bitmasking though I would recommend reading:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/3-8a-bit-flags-and-bit-masks/